# Undefined property: DOMDocument::$tagName

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting the following error in my debug.log file for WP.

PHP Notice:  Undefined property: DOMDocument::$tagName in .../wp-content/themes/theme-name/libs/oi/functions.php on line 441

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in .../wp-content/themes/theme-name/libs/oi/functions.php on line 441

```
function oi_display_hierarchy( $nav_menu, $args )
{
    if( ! is_single() )
    {
        return $nav_menu;
    }

    $menuXML = new SimpleXMLElement( $nav_menu );
    list($current) = $menuXML->xpath( "//li[contains(@class,'current-menu-parent')]" );
    if( !empty( $current ) )
    {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($current);
        while($node)
        {
            $node = $node->parentNode;
            if( $node->tagName == 'li' ) // 441 - The problem line
            {
                $classes = $node->getAttribute('class');
                $node->setAttribute('class', $classes . ' current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor');
            }
        }
    }

    return str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', $menuXML->asXML());
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'oi_display_hierarchy', 11, 2);
```

Any ideas what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the current [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) object parent node on the line just above:

```
$node = $node->parentNode;
```

So after that `$node` will be changed to a [`DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode) (`DOMElement` inherit of `DOMNode`). `tagName` property is not part of the definition of `DOMNode`, it's specific to `DOMElement` - this is why it throw an error.

Everything in xml is a node - text, lines, comments... So a `DOMNode` **can be** a tag, but it can be something else too. So we need to check the type of the node with the following:

```
if($node->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) { // Node is a DOMElement
```

That way we're sure that $node is a `DOMElement`, and then can use safely `tagName` property.